# Scraping news articles into one single list with NewsPaper library in Python?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, append, python-newspaper

Dear Stackoverflow community!

I would like to scrape news articles from the CNN RSS feed and get the link for each scraped article. This workes very well with the Python NewsPaper library, but unfortunately I am unable to get the output in a usable format i.e. a list or a dictionary.

I want to add the scraped links into one SINGLE list, instead of many separated lists.

```
    import feedparser as fp
    import newspaper
    from newspaper import Article

    website = {"cnn": {"link": "http://edition.cnn.com/", "rss": "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss"}}

    for source, value in website.items():
        if 'rss' in value:
            d = fp.parse(value['rss']) 
            #if there is an RSS value for a company, it will be extracted into d

            for entry in d.entries:
                if hasattr(entry, 'published'):
                    article = {}
                    article['link'] = entry.link
                    print(article['link'])
```

The output is as follows:

```
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/5aHaFHz2VtI/index.html
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/_O8rud1qEXA/joe-walsh-trump-gop-voters-sot-crn-vpx.cnn
http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/xj-0PnZ_LwU/index.html
.......
```

I would like to have ONE list with all the links in it i.e:

```py
    list =[http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/5aHaFHz2VtI/index.html , http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/_O8rud1qEXA/joe-walsh-trump-gop-voters-sot-crn-vpx.cnn , http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~3/xj-0PnZ_LwU/index.html ,... ]
```

I tried appending the content via a for loop as follows:

```
    for i in article['link']:
        article_list = []
        article_list.append(i)
        print(article_list)
```

But then the output is like this:

```
['h']
['t']
['t']
['p']
[':']
['/']
['/']
['r']
['s']
...
```

Does anyone know an alternative method, how to get the content into one list?
Or alternatively a dictionary as following:

```
    dict = {'links':[link1 , link2 , link 3]}
```

Thank you VERY much in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your code like this and see if it works:

```
article_list = []
for entry in d.entries:
            if hasattr(entry, 'published'):
                article = {}
                article['link'] = entry.link
                article_list.append(article['link'])
```

Comment: YES! This actually worked! Thank you so much - I spent hours on trying to figure this out. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Mercury - Glad it worked for you! Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Hi there again!

Unfortunately, as soon as I change the source to multiple rss links, it only appends the second ones to the list. 

For example, I added the CNBC link:

website = {"cnn": {"link": "http://edition.cnn.com/", "rss": "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss"},
          "cnbc":{"link": "https://www.cnbc.com/", "rss": "https://www.cnbc.com/id/10000664/device/rss/rss.html"}}

And now the list is only filled with CNBC links. Do wou know maybe how I can solce this problem, and append all the links from all the sources?

Thank you in advance!!
Ps. Answer is accepted! :-)

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the definition of `website` in the case of multiple links. The best way to handle it (and probably what SO prefers in these cases) is to post the new issue as a different question with the code you use. This will also add visibility to the new problem and allow others to chime in.

Comment: Ok, I will post a new question regarding this issue. Thanks a lot!