# Scraping multiple news article sources into one single list with NewsPaper library in Python?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, python-newspaper

Dear Stackoverflow community!

This is a follow up question regarding a previous question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493176/scraping-news-articles-into-one-single-list-with-newspaper-library-in-python).

I would like to extract news paper URLS with the NewsPaper library from MULTIPLE sources into one SINGLE list. This worked well for one source, but as soon as I add a second source link, it extracts only the URLs of the second one.

```
    import feedparser as fp
    import newspaper
    from newspaper import Article

    website = {"cnn": {"link": "edition.cnn.com", "rss": "rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss"}, "cnbc":{"link": "cnbc.com", "rss": "cnbc.com/id/10000664/device/rss/rss.html"}} A

    for source, value in website.items():
        if 'rss' in value:
            d = fp.parse(value['rss']) 
            #if there is an RSS value for a company, it will be extracted into d
            article_list = []

            for entry in d.entries:
                if hasattr(entry, 'published'):
                    article = {}
                    article['link'] = entry.link
                    article_list.append(article['link'])
                    print(article['link'])
```

The ouput is as follows, only the links from the second source are appended:

```
    ['https://www.cnbc.com/2019/10/23/why-china-isnt-cutting-lending-rates-like-the-rest-of-the-world.html', 'https://www.cnbc.com/2019/10/22/stocks-making-the-biggest-moves-after-hours-snap-texas-instruments-chipotle-and-more.html' , ...]
```

I would like all the URLs from both sources to be extracted into the list.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem? 
Thank you very much in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`article_list` is being overwritten in your first `for` loop.  Each time you iterate over a new source you `article_list` is set to a new empty list, effectively losing all information from the previous source.  That's why at the end you only have information from one source, the last one

You should initialize `article_list` at the beginning and not overwrite it.

```
import feedparser as fp
import newspaper
from newspaper import Article

website = {"cnn": {"link": "edition.cnn.com", "rss": "rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss"}, "cnbc":{"link": "cnbc.com", "rss": "cnbc.com/id/10000664/device/rss/rss.html"}} A

article_list = [] # INIT ONCE
for source, value in website.items():
    if 'rss' in value:
        d = fp.parse(value['rss']) 
        #if there is an RSS value for a company, it will be extracted into d
        # article_list = [] THIS IS WHERE IT WAS BEING OVERWRITTEN

        for entry in d.entries:
            if hasattr(entry, 'published'):
                article = {}
                article['link'] = entry.link
                article_list.append(article['link'])
                print(article['link'])
```

Comment: Awesome - this worked perfectly fine! Thank you so much!